# Google Maps API Android build gradle parse failing with Google Services integration

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

So I am developing a map using Google Maps API for Android Studio. I can get a running build on my phone (Android 28.0) but it has no data on it, it's just a blank map. As soon as I start adding google services it gives me new errors.

```
ERROR: Failed to parse XML in C:\Users\Madzp\Desktop\MapsRedo\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
```

ParseError at [row,col]:[11,5]
Message: expected start or end tag
Affected Modules: app

This directs me to my manifest which edits the `<application>` tag with

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:hardwareAccelerated ="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <uses-library
        android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
        android:required="false"/>

</application>
```

How do I sort this parsing error as it always makes my project gradle sync fail?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you check your API key? Has it configured?